# what's the best way to remove and adding div with D3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Recently, I've been using D3.js to make interactive maps. While I'm trying to get my head around the mechanism of D3, there's a mystery came to me today while I'm trying to make a interactive updated div with D3 to show more information as a tooltip.

Basically, when I `click` on element there should be a `div` with updated content in it and a new position according to the existing element.

First I tried this:

`d3.select("body").selectAll(".tooltip").remove().append("div").attr("class", "tooltip");`

it doesn't work, but this one:
`d3.select("body").selectAll(".tooltip").remove();
 d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip").text("boa boa");`

when I split it into two line, it worked. I was assuming that the chaining method will work in D3 like JQuery but in this case it doesn't seem like it. So what am I missing here in such a situation?
I was assuming that even when `<div class = 'tooltip'></div>` does not already exist, the `remove()` would work on nothing but the `append()` after it should still append a `div` to the body. Isn't this true?

Thanks a lot in advance! I was just trying to think over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it didn't work is because you were attempting to append to something (`.tooltip`) when it no longer exists. Follow the code along as you have it chained. First you select the `.tooltip`, remove them, then you are attempting to append a `div` to that `.tooltip` but that `.tooltip` no longer exists.

On the other hand, the two liner works because you are appending that `.tooltip` to the body, which *does* exists.

Hope this helps.